# Être sous le/un charme

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Est-ce qu'il est possible de dire:

> Depuis hier je suis sous une espèce de charme (Since yesterday I'm under some kind of spell)

> Quand on est sous un/le charme français on oublie sa vie d'avant (When you're under "the french spell" you forget your previous life)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rien ne l'interdit de le dire mais plutôt qu'*être*, j'utiliserais *être tombé*:

> *Depuis hier, je suis tombé sous une espèce de charme.*

> *Quand on est tombé sous le charme de la France, on oublie vite sa vie d'avant.*

Comment: Il me semble que c'est ce que j'ai entendu plus souvent aussi, mais Google NGram ne paraît pas être d'accord. Est-ce que tu as une idée pourquoi ? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suis+tomb%C3%A9+sous+le+charme%2Csuis+sous+le+charme&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @DerekAllums *Tombé* exclut 50 % de la population. En ajoutant le féminin, la version avec *tomber* rattrape un peu son retard. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suis+sous+le+charme%2C%28suis+tomb%C3%A9+sous+le+charme%2Bsuis+tomb%C3%A9e+sous+le+charme%29&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3 mais je ne pensais pas que *tomber sous le charme* soit si récent.

Comment: mais oui c'est trop bête, j'aurais dû y penser, merci.